# Python PySerial Encoding - UTF 8 - Windows Vs. Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, pyserial

I'm writing a program that uses PySerial and needs to support both Windows and Linux. It's written in Python 2.7 for Windows and Python 2.7.4 for Linux.

On Linux(Ubuntu), when I write a string to the serial port

```
"""Write a string to the serial port and guarantee it was wrtiten out"""
serialPort.write(serialPattern)
serialPort.flush()
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 491, in write
    d = to_bytes(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyserial-2.7-py2.7.egg/serial/serialutil.py", line 76, in to_bytes
    b.append(item)  # this one handles int and str for our emulation and ints for Python 3.x
TypeError: an integer or string of size 1 is required
```

This same code works flawlessly in Windows. Eventually I tried encoding the string as utf-8 like this:

```
serialPort.write(serialPattern.encode("utf-8"))
```

And now it appears to work on both platforms.

So my questions is this: Why would Python/PySerial for Windows work with the default ASCII encoding, but Python for Linux require the string to be encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: The Linux and Windows encodings are both extended ASCII encodings. The windows-encoding goes by the misleading name ANSI-codepage and is normally an obsolescent 8-bit charset (Using UTF-8 is *difficult* there), the Linux one is part of the Locale and probably UTF-8.